# Android APK resign.jar is getting hanged

Tags: android-emulator

Actually i am working on android platform,I am using robotium for automation testing.In my scenario i dont have the code i only have the apk file of an application which i can resign it and do my automation testing.For resigning of signature of apk i am using resign.jar ,i got stuck up over here.

Actually i have set Android_Home and every other variables are set but when i drop the apk file and save it by some name the .jar file is getting hanged up.

What might be the issue.!

Answer (score 0):

If you get the apk file you have to test e.g. from your developers, do the following steps to resign it with your keystore:

- Rename the apk file into a zip file
- Unzip the zip file
- Delete the META-INF folder
- Rezip the folder again to a zip file
- Rename the zip file again to an apk file
- Open a terminal and follow the Android SDK developer guide http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

That’s it! Afterwards you should be able to test against an apk file!